# Scroll multiple virtualized itemcontrols

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a calendar-like control with a column for each day of the week and seven ObservableCollections which can contain up to a hundred or more items each.

I'd like to be able to vertically scroll through them **[Edit]** simultaniously **[/Edit]** while having them virtualized.

Right now I've got the following layout

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Monday -->
        <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Monday}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" ... />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MyControl Item="{Binding}" ... />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>

        ...

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, the performance is questionable and I think it's due to the ScrollViewer allowing the Grid -> Border -> VirtualizingStackPanel to vertically expand and not virtualize at all. Is that the case?

(Sidenote: I've tried to remove the ScrollViewer and add CanVerticallyScroll="True" to the VirtualizingStackPanels and expected them to scroll independently to check if performance is any better but they wouldn't scroll at all)

What could be a correct layout for this?

**Edit**: Displaying 100 elements for each column (700 total) takes 13 seconds, scrolling is actually okay

**[Edit2]**: 
Due to the required simultanious scrolling, I've tried to create a new collection that contains "one row" (7 items) and that as template in a listview. Horrible results [/Edit2]

Comment: Hope you have a good reason for using a custom control, usually you can get away with `DataTemplate` instead. I think the delay might be due to a complex template, but we can't see that, so this is just a guess.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Thanks for your input! Basically because the control might get reused somewhere else. Where might be the benefit to put the content of it in the datatemplate directly?

Comment: Ideally you would have it defined in a resource dictionary as a static resource and then reference it in your xaml where you need it. App.xaml would be a perfect place to start.

Comment: I'll check if that would be a possibility, but I've got 540 lines of code behind it.

Comment: Do you mean `C#` code or just xaml? And if you have code behind then there is probably a good reason for it, out of curiosity why do you have code behind?

Comment: `DataTemplate` doesn't have the overhead of creation of `UserControl`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX mostly drag and drop logic and some contextmenu stuff which could be moved I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the issue was to not render the seven columns each with one virtualized ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer (which seemed to expand the ItemsControls and make them draw all controls) but render with one ItemsControl, solving the scrolling through ItemsControl.Template and displaying one **row** at a time.

I created a new collection and grabbed the objects "per row"

```
for(int PI = 0; PI < MathHelper.Max(Monday.Count, Tuesday.Count, Wednesday.Count, Thursday.Count, Friday.Count, Saturday.Count, Sunday.Count); PI++)
{
    Presentation.Add(new WeekRow(
        Monday.Count > PI ? Monday[PI] : null,
        Tuesday.Count > PI ? Tuesday[PI] : null,
        Wednesday.Count > PI ? Wednesday[PI] : null,
        Thursday.Count > PI ? Thursday[PI] : null,
        Friday.Count > PI ? Friday[PI] : null,
        Saturday.Count > PI ? Saturday[PI] : null,
        Sunday.Count > PI ? Sunday[PI] : null
        ));
}
```

And displayed them using this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Presentation}" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Focusable="False">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel 
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <MyControl Item="{Binding Monday}" Grid.Column="0" ... />

                ...

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate
</ItemsControl>
```

What's really important here, is to set the CanContentScroll-Property of the ScrollViewer to true or otherwise the virtualization **will not work** (who knows why). This was missing in @Marc's answer.

**Edit:** What's also worth mentioning is, that to get "smooth scrolling" (well, as "smooth" as wpf can get..), one has to set VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit to "Pixel". But it *only* works when set to the ItemsControl, **and not** to the ScrollViewer, ItemsPresenter or VirtualizingStackPanel itself. For whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

To make a ItemsControl virtualizing you not only need to use the VirtualizingStackPanel but also add a ScrollViewer to the template of the ItemsControl (normally the ItemsControl does not have a ScrollViewer).

Add this template inside your ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                          Focusable="False">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

As an different solution you can of course replace your ItemsControl with a ListBox, which already has everything needed for virtualizing your list.

Comment: Thanks! Where's the VirtualizingStackPanel in this example? And this would result in the columns scroll independently instead of simultaniously, right?

Comment: This is not the entire code only the part you need to add inside your ItemsControl. And yes this will make each column scroll independently.

Comment: Okay thanks, that sadly is not what I want to achieve, the simultaneous scroll is a must. I guess I could let the others follow but they would just stop at the end while others keep scrolling